# How to print the shortest and the longest sentence of a text file using python sent_tokenize?

Tags: python, nltk

I have a program that:

a) counts and displays the number of tokens in each sentence of a text file entered by the user 
b) displays the sentence number: sentence 1, sentence 2.... 
c) displays the length in tokens of each sentence

Problem: I want to display also the longest and the shortest sentence of the file, but my program does not count the sentence with the maximum number of tokens and the sentence with the minimum number of tokens. I don't get an error message but the output I get is:

The longest sentence of this file contains 1 tokens

The shortest sentence of this file contains 1 tokens

The mean sentence length of this file is:  56.55384615384615

I've tried to use the functions max() and min() for this. My code is below.

```
def sent_length():
    while True:
        try:
            file_to_open =Path(input("\nYOU CHOSE OPTION 1. Please,   insert your file path: "))
            #opens and tokenize the sentences of the file
            with open(file_to_open) as f:
                words = sent_tokenize(f.read()) 
                break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("\nFile not found. Better try again")
        except IsADirectoryError:
            print("\nIncorrect Directory path.Try again")
    print('\n\n This file contains',len(words),'sentences in total')

    sent_number=1

    for t in words:
        a=word_tokenize(t) #tokenize the sentence
        #displays the sentence number and the sentence length
        print('\n\nSentence',sent_number,'contains',len(a),   'tokens')
        sent_number+=1 


    wordcounts = [] 

    with open(file_to_open) as f:
        text = f.read()
        sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
        for sentence in sentences:
            words = word_tokenize(sentence)
            wordcounts.append(len(words)) # appends the length of each sentence in a list
    #calculates mean sentence length
    average_wordcount = sum(wordcounts)/len(wordcounts) 

    #loop through the sentences of the file and tokenize each sentence
    for x in words:
        tokenized_sentences=wordpunct_tokenize(x) 

    longest_sen = max(tokenized_sentences, key=len) #gets the maximum  number
    longest_sen_len = len(longest_sen)
    shortest_sen = min(tokenized_sentences, key=len) #gets the minimum number
    shortest_sen_len = len(shortest_sen)

    print ('\n\n The longest sentence of this file contains',longest_sen_len, 'tokens')
    print ('\n\n The shortest sentence of this file contains',shortest_sen_len,'tokens')
    print('\n\nThe mean sentence length of this file is: ',average_wordcount)
```

My expected result would be a print like:

e.g.The longest sentence of this file contains 70 tokens

e.g.The shortest sentence of this file contains 10 tokens

e.g. The mean sentence length of this file is:  56.55384615384615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach may not be the best out there but it might just be helpful.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from statistics import mean

EXAMPLE_TEXT = "Hello Mr. Smith, how are you doing today? The weather is great, and Python is awesome. The sky is pinkish-blue. You shouldn't eat cardboard."

tokened_sent = sent_tokenize(EXAMPLE_TEXT)

main_dict = {}

for item in tokened_sent:
    item1 = list(item.split(" "))
    item2 = [' '.join(item1)]
    Length = []
    Length.append(len(item1))
    mydict = dict(zip(item2, Length))
    main_dict.update(mydict)

print('Maximum Value: ', max(main_dict.values()))
print('Minimum Value: ', min(main_dict.values()))
print('average Value: ', mean(main_dict.values()))
```